# open webpage from win forms application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, google-maps

i have Form that show location (Latitude and Longitude) of top 5 nearest technisions.
in that form I also need to show Google Map that will show the technisions (as markers).

How can i show it in WinForm appliction?

what will be best to use for that mission?

The question that i am trying to solve is, How can i load a local html page in a Winform application (the html page will call GoogleMaps API) and show a custom map, according to the value that i sent to GoogleMaps API?

Comment: read this: [how-to-add-web-browser-capabilities-to-a-windows-forms-application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-add-web-browser-capabilities-to-a-windows-forms-application) and see this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xh7R9Q5jPpk)

Comment: [Geolocation: Displaying User or Device Position on Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geolocation) on Google Developers.

Comment: @HasanMahmood thanks. i will have to use GoogleMaps to show some dynamic content by values that i send it. so i need to call a local webpage that calls Google API, can i achieve that? should i add a webform page o the solution? that code that i'll have to run is like the code that Jimi posted a link too..

Comment: @E.Meir, can you please read the article and see the video. I think you can do that.

Comment: @HasanMahmood in the video it shows how to implment a web browser in win forms application (the bowser open a URI that the user type in the text box). 
I am looking to open a self hosted page, that i edit the content (html, js.. of it)

Comment: Have you tried pointing the embedded browser at your self-hosted page (instead of letting a user type a URL)? Ex. webBrowser1.Navigate() could point to a html file on your PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tgolisch` comment led me to the answer:

```
 string curDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();         
 this.webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(String.Format(@"file://{0}\WebAssets\google.html", curDir));
```

in the form UI i have a WebBrowser control, `this.webBrowser1.Url=...`
is loading local `html code` to the `WebBroweser` control.

** `webBrowser` control is using IE7 behind the hood, for google maps to work (we need a browsewr that support html5, i had to add this `meta` data tag (without it > errors appeared)

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

That way the IE that's being loaded is the current version that you have installed on your machine.